# Filtrering on multiple values in Power BI - Text does contain one of multiple values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a dataset in PowerBI where I want to be able to identify the rows that contains one of the three following words: Water, Gas, Electriciy.

If a row contains the word, the value in the new column "Matching" should be set to 1 and if no match to null

My problem is, that I need to add these multiple values to the `Text.Contains` and I'm not really sure how to do that the most easily in M-language.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Matching", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "Water",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then 1 else null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [List.MatchesAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-matchesany) to check each element of a list and return true if any of them match.

The looks like this in M:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Matching",
    (C) => List.MatchesAny(
               {"Water", "Gas", "Electricity"},
               each Text.Contains(C[Column1], _)
           )
  )
```